# Swift/MySQL/PHP: how to write an ios app using an online database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I have just fineshed an apprenticeship in a little company for which I have developed management web application hosted in ARUBA together with mysql DB. Now for my "Mobile application" course I would like to realize an iOS app as a mobile version for that web application: pratically I could create a new frontend as an iOS app. I am supposed to use Swift and I am totally new to iOS development. So I would like to ask if you can give me some tutorials about how to use swift and php to connect to a database and perform CRUD operations. Before suggesting this idea to my teacher I would like to make some practice and see if I am able to create this kind of app.
What do you say?

Comment: Go for it. Other than that there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This course](https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud421) looks promising, though I haven't done it myself, so I'm not sure.

Think of this project in three parts:

1. Creating your MySQL database
2. Developing your PHP API to "talk to" the database - this is the mediator between the client and the database
3. Developing the client code

It sounds like you've done some web development, so can I assume that you know how to do number 1 and 2 above? You can create the PHP almost exactly like you would for a website, and it has a great function ([json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) to put everything you're sending to the client in JSON. There is a class called [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) to deal with the JSON received on the client end.

Do know that this is a big project; developing all the PHP and Swift code in addition to the database is no small feat.

To accomplish number 3, I would recommend reading up on [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/). [This tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c) and [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/tag/nsurlsession/) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. Yes, I can program quite well in PHP and with MySQL. In fact, I think I might re-use the php modules I wrote also for this appas backend and that all I have to do is to re-implement the frontend as an iOS app...